# Initializing portracker database files in nfsen

Tags: monitoring, ubuntu-12.04

I have configured nfsen on Ubuntu. After that I configured PortTracker plugin but database files cannot be initialized.

```
 #cd /usr/local/src
 #wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/nfdump/files/stable/nfdump-1.6.1/nfdump-1.6.1.tar.gz
 #tar xzfv nfdump-1.6.1.tar.gz
 # cd nfdump-1.6.1
 #./configure --prefix /usr --enable-nfprofile --enable-nftrack
 #make
 #make install
```

Making a directory for the nftrack data

```
# mkdir -p /var/log/netflow/porttracker
# chown www-data /var/log/netflow/porttracker
```

Setting the nftrack data directory in the PortTracker.pm module:

```
#vi /usr/local/src/nfsen-1.3.5/etc/nfsen-dist.conf 

   my $PORTSDBDIR = "/data/ports-db";
```

and changed it to:

```
my $PORTSDBDIR = "/var/log/netflow/porttracker";
```

Installing the plugins into the NFSen distribution

```
Dell-System-Inspiron-N4110:/usr/local/src/nfsen-1.3.5# cp contrib/PortTracker/PortTracker.pm /data/nfsen/plugins/
Dell-System-Inspiron-N4110:/usr/local/src/nfsen-1.3.5# cp contrib/PortTracker/PortTracker.php /var/www/nfsen/plugins/
```

Adding the plugin definition to the nfsen-dist.conf configuration

```
# vi /usr/local/src/nfsen-1.3.5/etc/nfsen-dist.conf 

@plugins = (
[ 'live', 'PortTracker'],
);
```

Re-running the installation

```
#./install.pl etc/nfsen-dist.conf
```

Initializing portracker database files

```
# sudo -u www-data nftrack -I -d /var/log/netflow/porttracker
```

Output

```
sudo: nftrack: command not found
```

**Log**

```
Sep 20 13:30:15 Dell-System-Inspiron-N4110 nfsen[24723]: PortTracker run: Profile: live, Time: 201209201325
Sep 20 13:30:15 Dell-System-Inspiron-N4110 nfsen[24723]: /usr/local/bin/nftrack -M /data/nfsen/profiles-data/live/Router -r nfcapd.20120
9201325 -d /var/log/netflow/porttracker -A -t 201209201325 -s -p -w /var/log/netflow/porttracker/portstat.txt
Sep 20 13:30:15 Dell-System-Inspiron-N4110 nfsen[24723]: Failed to execute nftrack: No such file or directory
Sep 20 13:30:15 Dell-System-Inspiron-N4110 nfsen[24723]: /usr/local/bin/nftrack -d /var/log/netflow/porttracker -S -p -w /var/log/netflo
w/porttracker/portstat24.txt
Sep 20 13:30:15 Dell-System-Inspiron-N4110 nfsen[24723]: Failed to execute nftrack: No such file or directory
Sep 20 13:30:15 Dell-System-Inspiron-N4110 nfsen[24723]: PortTracker run: Done.
Sep 20 13:30:15 Dell-System-Inspiron-N4110 nfsen[24723]: Cmd Decode: quit
Sep 20 13:30:15 Dell-System-Inspiron-N4110 nfsen[3191]: Run plugins done.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

At last I have solved this problem. To run `nftrack -I -d /var/log/netflow/porttracker` command, you must go `/path/to/nfsenx.x.x/bin`. Then run this command and It should work.